# Display Timer (countdown) into Notification (showNotification)

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I would like to know if it's possible and how to display an timer (countdown) into a notification.

I know how to display a notification with showNotification but I have no idea how to display countdown into the notification.

The code below create a new notification each second instead of update the content of the notification

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<button onclick="countdown();">Start</button>
<span id="counter"></span>
</body>
<script>
  function countdown() {
    let nIntervId;
    let temps = 10

    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      Notification.requestPermission()
        .then(() => navigator.serviceWorker.register('worker.js'))
        .then(() => navigator.serviceWorker.ready
        .then((s) => {
            count(s, temps);
        }))
      .catch(e => console.log(e.message));
    }
  }

  function count(s,temps){
    let nIntervId;
    if (!nIntervId) {
        nIntervId = setInterval(() => {
          let minutes = parseInt(temps / 60, 10)
          let secondes = parseInt(temps % 60, 10)
        
          minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes
          secondes = secondes < 10 ? "0" + secondes : secondes
        
          timerElement = `${minutes}:${secondes}`
        
          s.showNotification(timerElement);
        
          if (temps == 0) {
            clearInterval(nIntervId);
            nIntervId = null;
          }
      
          temps = temps <= 0 ? 0 : temps - 1
        }, 1000)
    }
}
</script>
</html>
```

Thanks for your help or idea